# What ticket options for the Tateyama Kurobe Alpine Route are available in 2023?

Tags: tickets, japan

I am wanting to travel the [Tateyama Kurobe Alpine Route](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tateyama_Kurobe_Alpine_Route) this year. In previous years a slightly discounted international tourist pass for the whole route called the ["Tateyama Kurobe Option Ticket"](https://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pdf/tateyama_kurobe_pass_150806_e.pdf) was available, but I can't find any current information about it.

The alternative [Alpine-Takayama-Matsumoto Area Tourist Pass](https://touristpass.jp/en/alpine/) is about twice the cost, because it's valid for 5 days and multiple trips, which is not what I need.

What ticket options are available for 2023? Was the Tateyama Kurobe Option Ticket cancelled because of the pandemic but they intend to offer it again this year? Or is there now no pass that ends up cheaper than buying tickets for each segment on the route individually?

Comment: I didn't find anything cheaper so just booked using the [official site](https://tateyama-kurobe-webservice.jp/AlpenTour/html/VW001W0010.html).